# Show that $f(x,y) = \frac{yx^4+4y^3x^2-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ goes to zero and its partial derivative not.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{yx^4+4y^3x^2-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$
This has derivative with respect to y 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) = \frac{(x-y)(x+y)(x^4+10y^2x^2+y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}
$$

I am seeking to show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y) = (0,0)$$ and that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)$$ does not exist, I am clueless though. Handling multivariate limits is a real struggle for me.

Edit: So I have handled the (easiest) non-existence of the limit by considering the limit along the path $(x,y)=(x,kx)$ where $x$ completely cancels and one can see the final expression depends on $k$. Can someone provide me with a tip on the first limit?

Comment: You are probably taking a mult-calculus class; you probably have a text-book; the textbook probably has worked out examples; you most probably did not look at them.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thank you for your comment you are correct about me taking a calculus class. May I suggest the alternate phrasing of your comment: "Have you checked in your notes for relevant examples?" - I believe I have, but I will look at it again.

Comment: You may use polar coordinates in the first case, i.e., $x=r\cos(t)$, $y=r\sin(t)$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Sorry, how? I end up with a bunch of angles in the numerator that I cannot make cancel.

Comment: The numerator is something like $r^5$ times a sum of products of sines and cosines while the denominator is just $r^4$. Does that help?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe So I just bound the sin and cosines numerically by one and see the result still converge (higher order r in numerator). I thought the angle was not allowed in the expression at all. I can accept your suggestion as an answer if you like.

Comment: @user280528 Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use polar coordinates, $x=r\cos(r)$, $y=r \sin(t)$.Then 
the numerator is something like $r^5$
 times a sum of products of sines and cosines while the denominator is just $r^4$.

Does that help?